# Android - Facebook error does not call authorize when user revoke permission

Tags: android, facebook

I am puzzled by an issue of reauthorizing users after users revoke the permissions. When user revokes the permission of the application, an error dialog is displayed when trying to do something like posting on facebook. However, `authorize()` is not being called. Is it an issue with my code

```
                public void doAuthentication()
            {
                    // here all your FB authentication related stuff.

                mPrefs = getPreferences(MODE_PRIVATE);
                String access_token = mPrefs.getString("access_token", null);
                long expires = mPrefs.getLong("access_expires", 0);
                if(access_token != null) {
                    facebook.setAccessToken(access_token);
                }
                if(expires != 0) {
                    facebook.setAccessExpires(expires);
                }

                /*
                 * Only call authorize if the access_token has expired.
                 */
                if(!facebook.isSessionValid()) {

                facebook.authorize(Cats.this, new String[] { "publish_stream", "read_stream", "publish_checkins", "offline_access"}, new DialogListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(Bundle values) 
                    {
                        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = mPrefs.edit();
                        editor.putString("access_token", facebook.getAccessToken());
                        editor.putLong("access_expires", facebook.getAccessExpires());
                        editor.commit();
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onFacebookError(FacebookError error) {}

                    @Override
                    public void onError(DialogError e) {}

                    @Override
                    public void onCancel() {}
                });
            }

            public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data)     {

    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    facebook.authorizeCallback(requestCode, resultCode, data);
}
```

Comment: What's your problem here? that you can't send the user back to the authentication flow?

Comment: Yes. Once user revokes the permission and tries to share/post information, the facebook error dialog appears and does not ask for the permission again.

Comment: Sorry, i'm not familiar enough with the Android SDK; in the general case there should be no problem asking the user to reauthenticate (assuming they didn't outright block the app, and merely removed the permissions), but i don't know the auth flow on android SDK well enough to know why it wouldn't work for you

Answer (score 0):

```
    public void share(){
    if (! facebook.isSessionValid()) {
        loginAndPostToWall();
    }
    else {
        postToWall(messageToPost);
    }
}
   public void loginAndPostToWall(){
    facebook.authorize(this, PERMISSIONS, Facebook.FORCE_DIALOG_AUTH, new LoginDialogListener());
}

     public void postToWall(String message){
    Bundle parameters = new Bundle();
    parameters.putString("message", message);
    parameters.putString("description", "topic share");
    try {
        facebook.request("me");
        String response = facebook.request("me/feed", parameters, "POST");
        Log.d("Tests", "got response: " + response);
        if (response == null || response.equals("") ||
                response.equals("false")) {
            showToast("Blank response.");
        }
        else {
            showToast("Message posted to your facebook wall!");
        }
        finish();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        showToast("Failed to post to wall!");
        finish();
    }
}
   class LoginDialogListener implements DialogListener {
    public void onComplete(Bundle values) {
        saveCredentials(facebook);
        if (messageToPost != null){
            postToWall(messageToPost);
        }
    }
    public void onFacebookError(FacebookError error) {
        showToast("Authentication with Facebook failed!");
        finish();
    }
    public void onError(DialogError error) {
        showToast("Authentication with Facebook failed!");
        finish();
    }
    public void onCancel() {
        showToast("Authentication with Facebook cancelled!");
        finish();
    }
}

private void showToast(String message){
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), message, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
private void clearCredentials() {
    AsyncFacebookRunner mAsyncRunner = new AsyncFacebookRunner(facebook);
    mAsyncRunner.logout(FacebookStatus.this, new RequestListener() {
        @Override
        public void onComplete(String response, Object state) {

            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

                @Override
                public void run() {
                    saveCredentials(facebook);
                    Log.i("facebook session2", ""+facebook.isSessionValid());
                    showToast("You Succesfully logged out of the app");
                    finish();

                }
            });

        }

        @Override
        public void onIOException(IOException e, Object state) {}

        @Override
        public void onFileNotFoundException(FileNotFoundException e,
                Object state) {}

        @Override
        public void onMalformedURLException(MalformedURLException e,
                Object state) {}

        @Override
        public void onFacebookError(FacebookError e, Object state) {}
    });

}
```